# Not Able to Display Tabs in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

i am targeting a tablet 3.2 version. i am displaying a listactivity in the left side of the screen and when user clicks on a listitem the details get displayed on the right side of the screen. as i have different details layout for each item clicked i am displaying a fragment on the right side of the screen. i have a requirement to display on a tabbed layout on the detail section. i extended a fragment and in oncreateview inflated an xml with tabhost as root element. but somehow the fragment is not being inflated. for each tab i have a list view to display.below is the code section...the error i get is NullPointerException.

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

    public class Projects extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

private int mCurrentTab;
private TabHost mTabHost; 

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View  tablayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.projects, null);
    mTabHost = (TabHost)tablayout.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    final View v1 = tablayout.findViewById(R.id.webprojects);
    final View v2 = tablayout.findViewById(R.id.androidprojects);
    final View v3 = tablayout.findViewById(R.id.iphoneprojects);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("WEB").setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {


        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v1;
        }
    }));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("ANDROID").setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v2;
        }
    }));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("IPHONE").setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v3;
        }
    }));


    return tablayout;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setRetainInstance(true);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FragmentTransaction FrgTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if(tabId.equals("WEB"))
    {
        if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null)
        {
            FrgTra.replace(R.id.webprojects, new ProjectsListFragment("WEB"), tabId).commit();

        }
    }

    if(tabId.equals("ANDROID"))
    {
        if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null)
        {
            FrgTra.replace(R.id.androidprojects, new ProjectsListFragment("ANDROID"), tabId).commit();
        }
    }

    if(tabId.equals("IPHONE"))
    {
        if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null)
        {
            FrgTra.replace(R.id.iphoneprojects, new ProjectsListFragment("IPHONE"), tabId).commit();
        }
    }

}
    }
```

and the xml i am using is :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/webprojects" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            >
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/androidprojects" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            >
            </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/iphoneprojects" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            >
            </FrameLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
                   </LinearLayout>
                      </TabHost>
```

please help me resolve this issue....

Answer (score 0):

Unsure your content is initialised correctly with the 
    new TabHost.TabContentFactory() 
call.

I've found that populating a Tab requires an activity that might need extras to extract your information eg the cursor id.  You might then need to set the text displayed on the tab and an icon or icon selector so that tab selection is more tailored to your user's experience.

```
Resources _res = app.getResources();
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
Intent _intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WEB_TabActivity.class);
     _intent.putExtra("whenNeeded", whenNeeded);

// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("WEB")
    .setIndicator(_res.getString(R.string.WEB_Displayed_Tab_Text),
        _res.getDrawable(R.drawable.WEB_icon_selector))
    .setContent(_intent));
```

Example selector is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use color-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/WEB_ICON_color"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/WEB_ICON_Grey" />
</selector>
```

you then code WEB_TabActivity as any Activity class that would display your desired data.

Comment: sorry solarsheriff , even though i have changed my listfragment to listactivity and tried it doesnot work.i have made all changes as u suggested . i still have the same error. in android documentation it says i have to use tabactivity. but it is deprecated now.  ok forget about my code. i am ready to change it. all i need is when i click on an item in the list(which is in the left side of the screen) i need a tabbed layout on the right side of the screen) i am targeting a tab and version 3.2. if you can please suggest me wat i should do to acheive it

Comment: i'm unsure how to help with that vivek, setting the tab programmatically hasn't worked for me (version 2.2). My suggestion is doing simple hello world examples for each tab layout. Selecting an item from your list would make the fragment visible in a single activity / layout, you might then be able to simulate the tabhost interface without using it directly.

Comment: Using the viewholder design pattern in your own CursorAdapter is one way.  A viewholder is simply a data structure that negates the need to call findViewById().  Additionally, when building your list, you can assign objects to the views contained in your list item layout using .setTag().  The link between List and layout is made when you handle the onListItemClick event.  You identify the view form your list item layout and use . getTag().  This facilitates tailored behaviours depending on the item clicked.

Answer (score 0):

** CURSOR ADAPTER AND VIEW HOLDER PATTERN

```
/**
 * Adapter that allows us to match product items to layout fragment<p/>
 * 
 * @author The Solar Sheriff
 */
public class MyItemListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


public final static String  TAG = "MyItemListAdapter";

/**
 * Constructor from a list of items
 */
    private LayoutInflater  _li;
    private Context         _context;
    private Cursor          _in;
    private int         _productName,
                    _count;

    public OrderItemListAdapter(Context _Context, Cursor _In) {
        super(_Context, _In, true);

        _context            = _Context;
        _li                 = LayoutInflater.from(_context);
        _in                 = _In;

        _productName        = _in.getColumnIndex("product_name");           
        _count              = _in.getCount();


}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _in.getCount();
}

@Override  
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {  
  View _view = _li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);  
  return _view;  
}

private ViewHolder mapItemViewHolder(View _v){
    ViewHolder _itemHolder = new ViewHolder();

    //Map the views to the ViewHolder
     _itemHolder.productName = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.itemProductName);

return _itemHolder;
}

@Override  
public void bindView(View _cView, final Context _context, final Cursor _c) {  
    ViewHolder _itemHolder;

    // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
    // by ListView is null.
    if (_cView == null) {
        _cView = _li.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);          
        _itemHolder = mapItemViewHolder(_cView);
     _cView.setTag(_itemHolder);
    }
    else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access
        // Can also get a view with no tag so check for null
        if ((_itemHolder = (ViewHolder) _cView.getTag()) == null) {
                _itemHolder = mapItemViewHolder(_cView);
                _cView.setTag(_itemHolder);
        }        
    }



//*** TEXT VIEWS ***

    // Bind the data using the holder.
    _itemHolder.productName.setText(_c.getString(_productName));  

    for(String _display : TabLayouts ) {
  if ( _display.equals("WEB") ) _itemHolder.productName.setTag(Integer.toString(R.layout.WEB_layout));  
  if ( _display.equals("IPHONE") ) _itemHolder.productName.setTag(Integer.toString(R.layout.IPHONE_layout));  
  if ( _display.equals("ANDROID") ) _itemHolder.productName.setTag(Integer.toString(R.layout.ANDROID_layout));  

    }

}    

static String TabLayouts = { "WEB","IPHONE","ANDROID"};

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView        productName;
}   
 }
```

// YOUR onSelectedItem LISTENER DOES

```
    MyList.setOnItemSelectedListener( new OnItemSelectedListener() {            

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> _item, View _View, int _selection, long _id) {


        ViewGroup _parent  = (ViewGroup)_item.getParent();          
        TextView  _productName = (TextView)_parent.findViewById(R.id.itemProductName);      

        int _showLayout = Integer.valueOf(_productName.getTag());

        //*** e.g. Inflate your fragment layout ***


        }       

    });
```

Hope this gives you a successful path to follow :)

Comment: you got my requirement wrong. i need a tabbed layout on  the right side of my screen. when i click on a item in the listview, which is on the left side of my screen. wat ever u said i have already implemented when i click on the other list items

Comment: hey solarsheriff i did a silly mistake in my implementation, i dint call setup() function on the tabhost. it's ok now. i got it working. nyways thanks